# Laravel 5: How do I display a message and redirect after an Ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a simple blog post page that is submitting data through ajax jquery. 
It works fine, but at the moment, it returns the json response after submission.

What I need it to do is display the success message to the user on the submit page and then redirect him to the main articles page.

If I comment out `return Response::json($response);` I get a blank page but I don't wanna redirect him to another view automatically, I want to show him a message for 5 seconds and then redirect him.

And `$("#ajaxResponse").append(msg);` isn't doing anything.

This is my controller

```
public function store(Requests\ArticleRequest $request)
    {

        $article = new Article($request->all());
        Auth::user()->articles()->save($article);

        $response = array(
            'status' => 'success',
            'msg' => 'Setting created successfully',
        );

        return \Response::json($response);
    }
```

This is AJAX request

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var title = $('#title').val();
        var body = $('#body').val();
        var published_at = $('#published_at').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: host + '/articles/create',
            data: {title: title, body: body, published_at: published_at},
            success: function( msg ) {
                $("#ajaxResponse").append(msg);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And this is the view

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<h1>Write a New Article</h1>

<hr>

{!! Form::open(['url' => 'articles']) !!}
    <p>
        {!! Form::label('title', 'Title:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('title') !!}
    </p>

    <p>
        {!! Form::label('body', 'Body:') !!}
        {!! Form::textarea('body') !!}
    </p>

    <p>
        {!! Form::label('published_at', 'Date:') !!}
        {!! Form::input('date', 'published_at', date('Y-m-d'), ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </p>

    <p>
        {!! Form::submit('Submit Article', ['id' => 'submit']) !!}
    </p>
{!! Form::close() !!}

<h3 id="ajaxResponse"></h3>

@if($errors->any())
    <ul>
    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
    @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ URL::asset('assets/js/ArticleCreate.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: Since $response is an array, msg will be an object, so I'm pretty sure the append should be append(msg.msg), as you will also be able to access the status (using msg.status)

Comment: @Karl that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to set a timeout after you get your response back from the server. try this and adjust as needed. see example below.

```
return \Response::json($response);
```

in your js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var title = $('#title').val();
    var body = $('#body').val();
    var published_at = $('#published_at').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: host + '/articles/create',
        data: {title: title, body: body, published_at: published_at},
        success: function( data) {
            console.log(data);
            if(data.status == 'success') {
              alert(data.msg);
               setInterval(function () {
                alert("Hello");
               }, 3000);

            }else{
                alert('error');
                console.log(msg);
            }
        }
    });
  });
});
```

adjust as needed to adpat to your code.

[js fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/vtcr6myt/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.alert-me').click(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        alert("Hello");
    }, 3000);
  });

});
```

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. My code isn't working anyway, the ajax request is not being sent.

Comment: @Halnex You said it 's returning "returns the json response after submission." You script works just fine if you are getting response from the server?

Comment: Yes I am, but I deleted the content of `ArticleCreate.js` just to see if I would get a different error or message, but no, I got the same json response and it's because in my controller, I'm returning `return Response::json($response);` so the JS wasn't taking place. I then re-added the js content and edited `$('#frm').on('submit', function (e) {` because earlier I had the wrong ID. So now, I'm getting `POST http://localhost/laravel-5/public/articles/create 500 (Internal Server Error)` in the console.

Comment: I re-worked my code to get the data through and then I tried `setInterval` and it works like charm. Thanks :)